# Dynamically Generate PDF Reports with Sweave

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I'd like to generate a large number of reports. For simplicity, let's say I want to create 5 small pdf documents with only a simple title that cycles through a vector of names.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\dsfrac}[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\author{Me}
\title{\Sexpr{print(namelist)}}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

How would I go about cycling through the generation of these reports for:

```
namelist <- c("Tom","Dick","Harry","John","Jacob")
```

Thanks in advance!

PS: Bonus points for showing me how to define the name of the resulting PDF documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just call `Sweave` in a loop, as follows.

```
# Create the template file, "test.Rnw"
template <- "test.Rnw"
cat("
\\documentclass{article}
\\title{\\Sexpr{namelist[i]}}
\\begin{document}
\\maketitle
\\end{document}
", file=template)

# Parameters
namelist <- c("Tom","Dick","Harry","John","Jacob")

# Main loop: just compile the file, 
# it will use the current value of the loop variable "i".
for(i in 1:length(namelist)) {
  Rnw_file <- paste("test_", i, ".Rnw", sep="")
  TeX_file <- paste("test_", i, ".tex", sep="")
  file.copy(template, Rnw_file)
  Sweave(Rnw_file)
  system(paste("pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode",  TeX_file))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent, my lack of familiarity with Sweave was causing a bit of a hair pulling session.

Answer (score 5):

I prefer using `brew` + `Sweave/knitr` to do this kind of templates. Here is my approach:

```
# CREATE A BREW TEMPLATE ON FILE: template.brew
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\dsfrac}[2]{\frac{\displaystyle #1}{\displaystyle #2}}
\author{Me}
\title{<%= title %>}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}

# FUNCTION TO BREW AND WEAVE TEMPLATE TO PDF
gen_pdf <- function(title){
  rnw_file <- sprintf("%s.rnw", title)
  tex_file <- sprintf("%s.tex", title)
  brew('template.brew', rnw_file)
  Sweave(rnw_file)
  tools::texi2pdf(tex_file, clean = TRUE, quiet = TRUE)
  unlink(c(rnw_file, tex_file))
}

# GENERATING THE PDF FILES
namelist <- c("Tom","Dick","Harry","John","Jacob")
plyr::l_ply(namelist, gen_pdf, .progress = 'text')
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how <%= title %> is replaced by the elements in the vector namelist, but in my real life situation I have about 20 or 30 data points I need to be able to add, including figures - I'm not sure I can see how I would expand upon this. Interesting usage of `l_ply`.

Comment: `<%= title %>` is `brew` syntax, which is resolved when you `brew` the template. if you could post more specifics on what are the `variable` elements of your document, i can help set up the right `brew` template.

Comment: There are a few images that are generated dynamically (ggplot) and the rest is just numbers being shunted into place.